# IronPython calls TryGetMember instead of TryInvokeMember

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, dynamicobject

i'm trying to hand over a Dynamic object to Ironpython, but it seems Ironpython is not calling TryInvokeMember. Instead it calls TryGetMember and gives an Error that it cant call the result.

I have tried it with IronPython 2.7 and 2.6.10920

ExampleCode:

**DynamicObject:**

```
class ExampleDynamicObject: DynamicObject {
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
    out object result) {
        result = "TryGetMember";
        return true;
    }
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder,
    object[] args,
    out object result) {
        result = "TryInvokeMember";
        return true;
    }
}
```

**calling Mathode**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    dynamic example = new ExampleDynamicObject();
    var program = @"test = example.Call2(2)";

    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var scope = engine.CreateScope();
    scope.SetVariable("example", example);
    var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(program,
    SourceCodeKind.Statements);
    source.Execute(scope);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This calls the TryGetMember method and then throws a Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException "str is not callable"

This is thrown when u code something like 'test'(1)

So it seems that Python doesn't get that this is a Function call and instead just calls a Property.

But when i try to call it from C#

```
    Console.WriteLine(example.Call);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine(example.Call(1));
```

This will work:

```
TryGetMember
-------------------
TryInvokeMember
```

Has anyone a suggestion how to fix this?

**Solution: (edit: calledMethodeName has to be a List, otherwise nested methods wouldn't work)**

So thanks to Jeff.

When i design the Dynamic like that:

```
List<string> calledMethodeNames = new List<string>();

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
                                  out object result)
{
    calledMethodeNames.Add(binder.Name);
    result = this;
    return true;
}
public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    //calledMethodeNames last Element has stored the Name of the called methode (remeber to remove it)
    result = "TryInvoke";
    return true;
}
```

everything is working fine.

The clue is to return the Object itself as Member, than the object is callable and python calls the TryInvoke (not TryInvokeMember)

But TryInvoke ist called because after returning the object, the object itself is called. So InvokeBinder dont knows the Name of the called methode. So i store it into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour. IronPython uses `TryGetMember` followed by `TryInvoke` since the Python language has no concept of invoking a member: Python method calls are always an attribute lookup followed by a call.

The error you're getting is because you're setting `result` to a string (type `str`) and strings are not callable. You'll have to set `result` to either another dynamic object that implements `TryInvoke` or a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Python exception (str is not callable) it looks like IronPython first calls `TryGetMember` and since that function returns true it will use that object.

The `TryGetMember/TryInvokeMember` should only return `true` if they succeeded. For example that means `TryGetMember` should return `true` if and only if there actually is a member that matches the `binder` parameter.

**Update:** in C# `Call(2)` is always a method call (I can't think of anything else it could be, please let me know if I'm wrong), so the C# compiler will use `TryInvokeMethod`. In Python however *any* object is callable if it has a `__call__` method, so `Call(2)` could either mean execute the method `Call` or get the member `Call` and execute `__call__` on it.

Comment: yes this i qhat i think too

I allready tested to return false, but then i get a "MessingMemberException". So even then hes not calling TryMemberInvoke

Comment: `x.Call(2)` could be a method call, or `Call` could be a property or field that's a delegate.

Comment: @JeffHardy Thanks, no clue why I haven't thought about that.